# How to attach the Vivus listener to the scroll of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vivus

I have a div that has `overflow: scroll` on it, and the svgs inside should animate on scroll, however they only animate in body (document), if I scroll down inside the div, it doesnt fire.

I tried to fire **[Vivus](https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus)** on scroll, but every time I scroll down or top it animates.

```
$('#div-scrollable').scroll(function () {
    new Vivus(document.querySelector('#svg'),{duration: 50});
});
```

I want to animate the svg the first time I scroll down inside the div.

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/orL30dLv/) - default 
[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/orL30dLv/1/) - scroll function

Comment: Is it the only place you call Vivus???

Comment: @alireza yes, I use it only inside that div.

Comment: May you please provide a jsfiddle  link or copy your html here? I need to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @alireza please click on jsFiddle kbd in the question

Comment: I see the second jsfiddle is what you want but it is rendering the animation each time you scroll to bottom or scrolling from the bottom. Why don't you simply set a flag to animate it for once?

Comment: @alireza if setting a flag can fix the problem I can use it. Please answer this question with your solution, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a flag is enough to handle the animation occurrence.

First, change your css to  `overflow-y: scroll;` like below

```
#div-scrollable {
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Then, use following script

```
flag = true;
$('#div-scrollable').scroll(function () {
    var DistanceFromBottom = Math.floor($("#div-scrollable")[0].scrollTop - ($("#div-scrollable")[0].scrollHeight - $("#div-scrollable").height()));
    if(-1 <= DistanceFromBottom && DistanceFromBottom <= 1 && flag){
        flag = false;
   }
   if(flag) new Vivus(document.querySelector('svg'),{duration: 50});

});
```

I worked and tested it on your jsfiddle and it should work.
let me know if there is any issue yet.